# Clarification on meaning of message "This creative type is no longer supported", and how to fix

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

The message is pretty self-explanatory, except that I'm not sure what "type" this creative is, since there is no "type" parameter, or "objective" parameter, or something like that. What does the phrase "this creative type" refer to? Perhaps it is implicitly determined by the subset of parameters I provide?

Here is my call:

ENDPOINT is `/act_<account_id>/adcreatives`

```
parameters: {
    object_store_url: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id284882215"
    image_hash: <image_hash>
    actor_image_hash: <another_image_hash>
    name: "install_c"
    body: "installing is good"
    call_to_action_type: "LISTEN_MUSIC"
    actor_name: "attributionator"
}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adcreative#create does not say anything about this type being unsupported (I'm following the "Mobile app install" row). Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: These look like the old parameters from before the July 2 migration: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/mobile-app-ads#migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the old way of creating these ads, which was deprecated on July 2nd. You'll have to create them as page posts now - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/mobile-app-ads#create

Comment: You should share more of the relevant changes in the new way of creating the ads in the post to help other users finding this question later (also in-case the link changes or becomes broken)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it doesn't like `LISTEN_MUSIC` as the `call_to_action_type`. Try using `USE_APP` instead and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: What about trying any of the other supported call to actions?

Comment: tried PLAY_GAME, LISTEN_MUSIC, USE_APP and figured that was sufficient to predict that call_to_action_type isn't the problem